# Time gap between short term visa and long term visa Austria

Tags: visa, dependent-visa, austria

I am currently a resident of Austria (RWR card). My fiance wants to apply for short term visa (visitors visa) to come to Austria just after marriage. Then she is planning to go back to India and apply for the Family Reunification visa (long term visa).

The question is, can she immediately apply for the long term visa just after the completion of the short term visa? OR is there any time gap needed?

PS: I am aware that one can stay in Austria for 90 days in every 180 days with short term visa. But not sure what is the rule for long term visa.

Comment: There is no time limitation for long term visas.  She can apply immediately.  But she could also apply for a long term visa right away.  Why are you planning to get a short-term visa first?